# How to interpolate line Z from sparse attribute values

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, interpolation, line

I have a series of end-to-end connected 3d lines which I'd like to add elevation values for all vertices on the lines which are currently `null` or `0`. How to accomplish this?

In the following image there are 3 lines, with 1 selected and vertices marked (green squares). Of these 3 lines there 2 vertices which have a Z value. Each Z-bearing vertex is on a different line. How to calculate and assign the intermediate vertex Z values between A and B? Again referring to the image, the resultant point *A.15* would be *661*, *A.14* is *662*, ...

[image: Highlighted line with vertex coordinates showing only 1 populated Z]

(For simplicity's sake this answer doesn't need to take X,Y distance between vertices into account. It's okay to simply divide A.Z & B.Z difference by number of points. Bonus kudos if that's included anyway ;-)

Both ArcGIS and QGIS/OGR solutions welcome; ditto ready to run tools and/or python.

Comment: [interpolate Z between polyline's vertices (IZ.InterpolateZsBetween ?)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70407/arcgis-10-interpolate-z-between-polylines-vertices-iz-interpolatezsbetween) looks relevant, if can figure out how to use from python, and span lines.

Comment: I've done this in C# using IZ, it's not that difficult but there's a bit of a learning curve ahead if you don't know ArcObjects or either VB.net or C#. It can be done in python I think... if you've only got a few good Z values you can create a terrain from the points and use Interpolate Shape http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Interpolate_Shape/00q90000006m000000/ to get the values onto the line (3d Analyst required). Also a good post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119249/interpolate-dxf-polyline-vertex-elevation-from-dtm that could be modified

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @MichaelMiles-Stimson, but generating a surface to interpolate from isn't viable. The known-Z points are too sparse. I know how to get straight to ArcObjects from python, it's the syntax for using the objects themselves that stymies me. I guess it's time I cracked that nut though. ;-)

Comment: There's a few good posts that utilize ArcObjects in python, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python for the basics and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142734/arcobjects-python-add-jpg-to-layout/142909#142909 for an example (unrelated) and a 'how to' read the ArcObjects API documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Very long but working:

```
# Tool assumes:
# a) 1st layer in Table of Conternt is TARGET polylineZ feature
# b) records in table sorted from upstream down 
# c) selected features maintain direction, i.e. upstream line END point equal downstream line START point
# d) missing z value for vertex is 0

import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
from arcpy import env
env.outputZFlag = "Enabled"
env.outputMFlag = "Enabled"

try:
    def showPyMessage():
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    destLR = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
    dDest=arcpy.Describe(destLR)
    destProj=dDest.spatialReference    
#  copy all lines to manageable list and merge
    g=arcpy.Geometry()
    geometryList=arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(destLR,g)
    nLines=len(geometryList)
    allPoints=geometryList[0].getPart(0)
    for i in range (1,nLines):
        part=geometryList[i].getPart(0)
        allPoints.extend(part)
    longLine=arcpy.Polyline(allPoints)

#  calc chainages
    dictFeatures,m = {},0
    for p in allPoints:
        dist=longLine.measureOnLine(p)
        dictFeatures[m]=(dist,p.Z)
        m+=1
#  find pairs
    first,nPoints,pairs=-1,len(allPoints),[]
    for i in range(nPoints):
        (d,z)=dictFeatures[i]
        if abs (z-0.0)>0.001: first=i; break
    if first==-1 or first==(nPoints-1):
        arcpy.AddMessage("Not enough z info")
        sys.exit(0)
    pairs.append((first,d,z))
    while True:
        second =-1
        for i in range(first+1,nPoints):
            (d,z)=dictFeatures[i]
            if abs (z-0.0)>0.001: second=i; break
        if second==-1:break
        first=second
        pairs.append((second,d,z))

# interpolate
    n=len(pairs)
    for j in range(1,n):
        first,d1,z1=pairs[j-1]
        second,d2,z2=pairs[j]
        dz=(z2-z1)/(d2-d1)
        for i in range(first+1,second):
            d,z=dictFeatures[i]
            z=z1 + dz*(d-d1)
            dictFeatures[i]=(d,z)
# update            
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(destLR,"Shape@") as cursor:
        aKey,m=0,0
        pz=arcpy.Point()
        newL=arcpy.Array()
        for row in cursor:
            shp=geometryList[m];m+=1
            part=shp.getPart(0)
            n=len(part)
            for i in range(n):
                p=part[i]
                d,z=dictFeatures[aKey]
                pz.X,pz.Y,pz.Z=p.X,p.Y,z
                newL.add(pz)
                aKey+=1
            newLine=arcpy.Polyline(newL,destProj,True)
            newL.removeAll() 
            arcpy.AddMessage(newLine.length)
            cursor.updateRow((newLine,))
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This provides a solid starting point, and is much better than the rabbit hole I was in, trying to adapt @Tomek's http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18655/108 to my circumstance.

Comment: you still have to figure out how to extrapolate points at the very start and end lines